# Passing UIView control events through UIView extension

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

This might be a weird question, but i'm trying to code like a pro which obviously i am not.

Right now i have an extension which uses UIView and my concept is making it like an alert

For example, i coded the following:

```
extension UIView {

    typealias completionHandler = (_ success:Bool) -> Void

    private var screenWidth: CGFloat {
        return UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    }


    public func showLuna(title messageTitle:String, message messageDescription:String, dissmiss dissmissDuration: TimeInterval) {

        let luna = UIView()

        luna.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 30, width: screenWidth - 30, height: 60)
        luna.center.x = self.center.x
        luna.backgroundColor = .white
        luna.addShadow(radius: 11, opacity: 0.2)
        luna.layer.cornerRadius = 10

    }

}
```

And on my other `ViewController`, I use this to present Luna

```
@IBAction func presentLuna(_ sender: Any) {

    self.view.showLuna(title: "Oooh", message: "Oops, something went horribly wrong!", dissmiss: 2.5);

}
```

At this very specific moment, I've been digging StackOverFlow for a day to find an answer. How do i attach a `gesture recognizer` or a function WITH a code block so the user can perform another task when luna gets tapped, or is that even possible with Extensions??

Comment: None of the code you posted actually shows any view. The `showLuna` function creates a new view and sets some properties on that view, but the new view is not displayed in any way. And putting all of this in a `UIView` extension doesn't seem appropriate. You probably want a `UIView` subclass that fully encapsulates this custom view.

Comment: @rmaddy, thanks for the comment. I didn't want to use the full code in this question. But what will be your approach with view subclassing? 'Cause i might go your way

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe what @rmaddy means by subclassing UIView:

First, create a subview so you can use it to respond to touch events:

```
class LunaView: UIView {

    typealias LunaViewCompletionBlock = (_ isSuccessful: Bool) -> Void

    var label: UILabel
    //other things you need

    var completionHandler: LunaViewCompletionBlock?

    init(frame: CGRect, /* other properties such as title and colour */, completionHandler: LunaViewCompletionBlock?) {
        self.completionHandler = completionHandler
        self.label = UILabel()

        super.init(frame: frame)

        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        //this is how we handle touch
        addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTouch)))

        addSubview(label)
        // set up frame or constraints(if you use autolayout) for label and other views
        // configure label.text and other things
    }

    func handleTouch() {
        completionHandler(/*true or false*/)
    }

    /*other methods needed in this class*/
}
```

Then, to use it, simply do this in the extension:

```
extension UIView {

    private var screenWidth: CGFloat {
        return UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    }


    public func showLuna(title messageTitle:String, message messageDescription:String, dissmiss dissmissDuration: TimeInterval, completionHandler: LunaView.LunaViewCompletionBlock) {

        let luna = LunaView(frame: /*size*/, /*other things like title*/, completionHandler: completionHandler)

        // set luna's center, shadow, auto-dismiss time, colour.....

    }

}
```

Comment: There should be no extension. All of that code belongs in `LunaView`.

Answer (score -1):

Answering your question:

> How do i attach a gesture recognizer or a function WITH a code block so the user can perform another task when luna gets tapped, or is that even possible with Extensions??

You can't detect a touch event on just a general `UIView` you need a `UIControl`. Since the `UIControl` type inherits from `UIView` you will be able to do any of your typical drawing or view hierarchy stuff but you can also setup touch actions and callbacks using `addTarget(:action:for:)` or other `UIControl` mechanisms.

Comment: This is incorrect. `UIView` extends `UIResponder` which provides all of the `touchesXXX` methods. Or you can add a gesture recognizer to any `UIView`. You do not need a `UIControl` to handle touches or gestures.